# How to combine deep learning models that perform different task

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I wish to know if there is any means to combine two or more deep learning models that perform different task so that I have one which can perform all those tasks.
Let's say for example I want to build a chat bot which adapts to your mood during a conversation. I have a model (CNN) for emotion detection on your face (using a camera as the chat is real-time), another one for speech recognition (speech-to-text) ... and I want to combine all those so that when you speak, it reads your facial expression to determine your mood, converts your speech to text, formulates an answer (taking your mood into consideration) and outputs voice (text-to-speech).

How can I combine all these different features/models into a single one